# How do I check if a string has exactly one of a certain character

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to scan strings to see if they have exactly one of a certain character.

For example if I'm looking for a question mark

```
Hello? I'm here
```

Will match the regex however

```
Hello? Are you listening?
```

Will not

I've tried `?{1}` and `?{1}[^?]+` but they both don't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do:

```
(\?)
```

and count the number of matches.

Or even more simply, count number of `?` in string using `tr///`

```
my $c = $string1 =~ tr/?//;
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Why the downvotes? Please tell me so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I get the feeling that people downvoted because you said "Note I don't really know `perl`", which made your answer seem like a lucky guess. Posting untried code and guesses is not a popular thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
my $cnt = () = $str =~ m/\Q$pat/g;

if ($cnt == 1) {
    # matched
}
else {
    # failed
}
```

`$pat` is the pattern (character in this case) you want to match, such as `'?'`.

Comment: @ikegami `$pat` suppose the pattern(character) that the asker want to match, such as '?'.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a particular character only, you can use the transliteration operator, `tr///`:

```
my $count = $string =~ tr/?/?/;
if( $count == 1 ) {
    ...
    }
```

With the transliteration operator, I can leave off the replacement side and any characters not lined up with a replacement character will use the previous replacement character. If there isn't a previous replacement character, it makes no replacement. I just leave out the second part of the `tr///`:

```
my $count = $string =~ tr/?//;
if( $count == 1 ) {
    ...
    }
```

This won't work for patterns though. This is strictly for character-to-character replacements. For a pattern, you do the same thing with [Lee Duhem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062981/2766176)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^?]*\?[^?]*$
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sT5oZ1)